# Exported Hyper-V not running in a new Laptop

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I exported a Hyper-V configuration which was hosted with Hyper-V with Windows 7 from a desktop with Hyper-V enabled and transported it to a Windows 10 machine.

However when I attempt to boot up the server it just says on a  blinking screen so it does. Does anybody have an idea as to what could be going wrong.

I made sure that I picked Gen ration 1 for the type of server and gave it 8gb of ram. I have 16gb of physical memory.

[image]

Comment: my question already has that generation1 is their?

Comment: You typed "Generation" as "Gen ration" so I missed it.